# Downloading MP3 and MP4 files using PHP

Tags: php, html, download, include, mp3

I am making a downloader for mp3 and mp4 and i want two php files in php with 2 buttons calling both php files but only the first php file works.

code for popup.php

```
<?php
    include "downloadmp3.php";
    include "downloadmp4.php";
?>
<html>
<head></head>
<body bgcolor="#E6E6E6">
    <form method="post">
        <label for="url">Download mp3:</label>
        <input type="text" name="url" value="" id="url">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Download">
        <hr>
    </form>
    <form method="post">
        <label for="url1">Download mp4:</label>
        <input type="text" name="url1" value="" id="url1">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Download">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

code for downloadmp3.php

```
<?php
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
    $url = (isset($_POST['url']) && !empty($_POST['url'])) ? $_POST['url'] : false;
    if (!$url) {
        echo "Vul alstublieft een url in";
    } else {
        $source = file_get_contents($url);
        $source = urldecode($source);

        // Verkrijg de video titel.
        $vTitle_results_1 = explode('<title>', $source);
        $vTitle_results_2 = explode('</title>', $vTitle_results_1[1]);

        $title = trim(str_replace(' – YouTube', ”, trim($vTitle_results_2[0])));

        // Extract video download URL.
        $dURL_results_1 = explode('url_encoded_fmt_stream_map', "url=", $source);
        $dURL_results_2 = explode('\u0026quality', $dURL_results_1[1]);

        // Force download van d  video.
        $file = str_replace(' ', '_', strtolower($title)).'.mp4';

        header("Cache-Control: public");
        header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$file");
        header("Content-Type: video/mp4");
        header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");

        readfile($dURL_results_2[0]);

        exit;
    }
}
?>
```

and code for downloadmp4.php

```
<?php
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
    $url = (isset($_POST['url1']) && !empty($_POST['url1'])) ? $_POST['url1'] : false;
    if (!$url) {
        echo "Vul alstublieft een url in";
    } else {
        $source = file_get_contents($url);
        $source = urldecode($source);

        // Verkrijg de video titel.
        $vTitle_results_1 = explode('<title>', $source);
        $vTitle_results_2 = explode('</title>', $vTitle_results_1[1]);

        $title = trim(str_replace(' – YouTube', ”, trim($vTitle_results_2[0])));

        // Extract video download URL.
        $dURL_results_1 = explode('url_encoded_fmt_stream_map', "url1=", $source);
        $dURL_results_2 = explode('\u0026quality', $dURL_results_1[1]);

        // Force download van d  video.
        $file = str_replace(' ', '_', strtolower($title)).'.mp4';

        header("Cache-Control: public");
        header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$file");
        header("Content-Type: video/mp4");
        header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");

        readfile($dURL_results_2[0]);

        exit;
    }
}
?>
```

**Updated:**
Form submitted for MP3 form works.
But form submitted for MP4 doesn't works.
Please provide an solution to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$file = 'Kalimba.mp3'; // file path


$contentType = 'audio/mpeg';

header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
header("Content-Type: $contentType");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=" . basename($file));
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
header("Expires: 0");
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate");
header("Pragma: public");
header("Content-Length: " . filesize($file));


readfile($file);
exit;
```

Answer (score 0):

Only first php file calls are working because of the following if condition:

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
```

Since downloadmp3.php has been included first therefore it's `if condition` is giving the result. 
Use proper form handler to make it work.
Also the best practice is to use unique names for the forms.

Answer (score 0):

This code is working fine for me in all the browsers and the downloaded file is playing good :
    download-audio.php

```
    <?php
    $file = $_GET['file'];
    header ('Content-type: octet/stream');
    header ('Content-disposition: attachment; filename='.$file.';');
    header('Content-Length: '.filesize($file));
    readfile($file);
    exit;
    ?>
```

test.html

```
    <a href='download-audio.php?file=duetsong.mp3'>Download Duet song MP3</a>
    <a href='download-audio.php?file=duetsong.mp4'>Download Duet song MP4</a>
```